# problem with matrix in c printing 0 at the summ of the diagonal elements

Tags: arrays, c, matrix

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define col 3
#define row 3
#define MIN 200
#define MAX 600

int main()
{
int Matriz[col][row] = {0};
int i, j;
int choose;
int sum = 0;

for (i = 0; i < row; i++) // primeira matriz com valores randomicos
{
    for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
    {
        Matriz[row][col] = MIN + (rand() % (MAX - MIN + 1));
        printf("%5d", Matriz[row][col]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    sum = sum + Matriz[i][i];
}
printf("%d", sum);
}
```

// my code prints the sum of the diagonals as 0 that's my question, what did i do wrong? i'm sorry  its my first time using stackoverflow  kinda confuse also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code

```
for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
{
    Matriz[row][col] = MIN + (rand() % (MAX - MIN + 1));
    printf("%5d", Matriz[row][col]);
}
```

`row` and `col` are not counters, use `i` and `j`, respectively.

Moreover, by using `row` (`3`) and `col` (`3`) as indexes, you're [off-by-one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error), as C uses 0-based array indexing. Thus, it invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code.

Comment: oh thanks, omg how could i miss that D:

Answer (score 1):

You only set one element in you matrix:

`Matriz[row][col] = ...` should be `Matriz[i][j] = ...`